# edittext not responsding .onClick (Extendscript)

Tags: javascript, extendscript

Why is this not working?

```
...
var newFolder = inputGroup.add ("group");
var newIFolder = newFolder.add("edittext",[0, 0, 300, 20]);
var addButton =  newFolder.add ("button", undefined, "Add");


var closeButton = window.add ("button", undefined, "Close");

closeButton.onClick = function() {
    window.close();}

addButton.onClick = function() {
    return newIFolder.text;
    window.close();
    alert(newFolder.text);}
...
```

Nothing happens onClick, the window just remains open.

Perhaps it's because of the groupings, somehow. I'll try to move it on top level, while I wait.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Edit: On top level no change :(
Edit2: I've tried, but no change :(

```
var addButton =  window.add ("button", undefined, "Add", {name: "ok"});
```

Comment: Try `window.cancelElement  = closeButton;` instead of the `closeButton.onClick = ...`

Comment: closeButton works fine, but I'll give it a go, perhaps, who knows, lol

Comment: if I type window.cancelElement  = closeButton; instead of the closeButton.onClick = ... then close button stops working as well, lol

Comment: Probably you have to move down the line `return...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is exactly the code I just tried and it works fine for me (InDesign 2022, Illustrator 2023, Photoshop 2023):

```
var window = new Window ("dialog");
// var newFolder = window.add ("group");
var newIFolder = window.add ("edittext",[0, 0, 300, 20]);
var addButton =  window.add ("button", undefined, "Add");
var closeButton = window.add ("button", undefined, "Close");

closeButton.onClick = function() {
    window.close();
}

addButton.onClick = function() {
    window.close();
    alert(newIFolder.text);
    return newIFolder.text; // <-- probably the problem was here
}

window.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the intial try didn't work ;), but this works ;D
Final solution ended like this:

```
var newFolder = inputGroup.add ("group");
var newIFolder = newFolder.add("edittext",[0, 0, 300, 20]);
var addButton =  newFolder.add ("button", undefined, "Add", {name: "ok"});

var closeButton = window.add ("button", undefined, "Close", {name: "cancel"});

addButton.onClick = function() {
window.close();
saveSettings (['I', 'F', 3], newIFolder.text);}
```

Once again, Thank you very much :D